# How to create and start any number of threads in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, loops, for-loop

I'm making a script to download images from a web page and I'm trying to make it multithreaded so it's a lot faster.

In the downloading function I had to set two arguments because when I set one (queue) I get this error:

```
TypeError: downloading() takes 1 positional arguments but 21* were given

** queue has 21 links
```

Code:

```
count = 0
queue = {"some urls", , , }
done = set()
path = 'foldername'


def downloading(queue, name):
    for imgs in queue:
        if imgs not in done:
            done.add(imgs)
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(imgs, path + '/' + imgs.split('/')[-1])
            global count
            count += 1
            print(str(count) + ' ' + name)
            print('Done:  ' + imgs.split('/')[-1])


def threads(queue):
    print('Start Downloading ...')
    th1 = Thread(target=downloading, args=(queue, "Thread 1"))
    th1.start()
    th2 = Thread(target=downloading, args=(queue, "Thread 2"))
    th2.start()
    th3 = Thread(target=downloading, args=(queue, "Thread 3"))
    th3.start()
    th4 = Thread(target=downloading, args=(queue, "Thread 4"))
    th4.start()
    th5 = Thread(target=downloading, args=(queue, "Thread 5"))
    th5.start()
    th6 = Thread(target=downloading, args=(queue, "Thread 6"))
    th6.start()
    th7 = Thread(target=downloading, args=(queue, "Thread 7"))
    th7.start()
    th8 = Thread(target=downloading, args=(queue, "Thread 8"))
    th8.start()
    th9 = Thread(target=downloading, args=(queue, "Thread 9"))
    th9.start()
    th10 = Thread(target=downloading, args=(queue, "Thread 10"))
    th10.start()
```

Comment: you could use `for-loop` to create all threads and keep them on list `th[1].start()`

Comment: are you sure you didn't use `args=queue` ? or `args=queue, "Thread 1"` without `()` ?

Comment: @furas and how to make this `for-loop` ?

i used `args=queue` and `args=(queue)` both are the same i think the set is the problem here like it's giving each element as an argument not all together as a set.

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nulla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\nulla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: downloading() takes 1 positional argument but 21 were given`

Comment: @furas nevermind i just figure it out i didn't know i should put  `,` after the argument.

let's get back to the `for-loop`

Comment: you run the same code 10 times - you could create list `all_threads = [ ]` and use `for x in range(10):` to run `t = Thread(...)`  t.start(), `all_threas.append(t)`. This way you have less code and you can change `range(10)` to run more threads. BUT more threads doesn't have to mean faster. Python use GIL which blocks threads and they don't run at the same time. Better use ThreadPool or [grequests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests) which can download at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a simple `for` loop on the number of threads you want. Of course you should save them somehow to probably `join` them in the end:

```py
def threads(queue):
    num_of_threads = 10
    print('Start Downloading ...')
    threads = []
    for i in range(1, num_of_threads+1):
        th = Thread(target=downloading, args=(queue, "Thread {}".format(i)))
        threads.append(th)
        th.start()
    return threads
```

---

As suggested, a `pool` will be helpful in this use-case since it will optimize the run to your system:

```py
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

def downloading(img):
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(img, path + '/' + img.split('/')[-1])
    global count
    count += 1
    print('Done:  ' + img.split('/')[-1])

def threads(queue):
    pool = ThreadPool()
    pool.map(downloading, queue)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Note that in this way you should change the `downloading` function to receive one argument that is a single image. The [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map) function sends each item of an iterable (second argument) to a function (first argument). This is also why the `done` set is not necessary since each image will be processed exactly once.

Comment: thanks, first code is working but i tested the [second one](https://pastebin.com/y8dRj7ec) and i got this [error](https://pastebin.com/ufp1DSq2)

Comment: Hi @albaraamarwan, I can't open those links. Can you explain what goes wrong?